# How to render a personalized button component on the same line with button elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components, styling

I am trying to render a couple buttons in react, as well as a specialized button component for special purposes. Here is my code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div id="headerButtons">
            <button id="HomeButton" onClick={this.linkHome}>Home</button>
            <button id="SupportPageButton" onClick={this.linkSupportPage}>Support</button>
            <AccountButton></AccountButton> 
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

However, when I run the web page, the AccountButton contents (right now just another button, but it will eventually hold several buttons) renders below the other two buttons.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this so that they all render in the same horizontal line?

Comment: What does AccountButton file look like? Also, you have them inside a DIV, but that doesn't mean that it will put them all inline. It really depends on the space of the screen your are trying to display them on, as the page will wrap them. Do you use any material-ui or react-bootstrap css styling, or any other styling library? If so, you might want to use those libraries to get it to display in a way you are looking for.

Comment: Right now, I am trying to styling them with pure css. The size of the screen is a full web page, so it shouldn't be wrapping it...I wondered if React creates a new line for different types of components for some reason?

Comment: It depends on your file for AccountButton. It could be returning a single DIV wrapped around it. It depends on how you define the render. @buzatto made a great answer that might help. Look at your render for your AccountButton and make sure that React is not creating a single DIV wrapper around that button.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!!! I wasn't thinking about that DIV in the AccountButton creating another container. But that makes sense now. Thanks Jason!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the wrapping div `headerButtons` css to flex:

```
#headerButtons {
  display: flex;
}
```

also at `AccountButton` use [fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to wrap your buttons, to avoid a `div` wrapper.

more about [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, which is why I asked Luke to share his AccountButton file as well.

Comment: that's reasonable to ask his file to get a better insight. since he said AccountButton would be a component of buttons, I expected that it would have a typical div wrapper that would break any layout.